# Android 5.1.1 - Build run-as binary

Tags: android, makefile, cmake, android-ndk, ndk-build

I'm trying to build a from android lollipop source the run-as binary.
I have download run-as package here : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+archive/android-cts-5.1_r28/run-as.tar.gz

Well, here is the Android.mk code :

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := run-as.c package.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libselinux
LOCAL_MODULE := run-as
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Werror
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

When I try to build, I receive this error :

```
Android NDK: Module run-as depends on undefined modules: selinux
*** Android NDK: Aborting (set APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true to allow missing dependencies)
```

So I add this line to my android.mk file

```
APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true
```

Then, I download headers files from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+archive/android-cts-5.1_r28/include/private.tar.gz) (android_filesystem_config.h) and from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libselinux/+archive/jb-mr1-dev-plus-aosp/include/selinux.tar.gz) (android.h) to include proper headers files needed for run-as.c

But when I tried to build again, I have this error:

```
./run-as.c:158: error: undefined reference to 'selinux_android_setcontext'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I guess I miss something on the build process...
An help would be appreciate.

Thanks